# calling multiple apis together in thread , Ios

Tags: ios, api

Is it possible to call multiple apis together in ios?

Let me try to clarify more with an example:

consider a category, sub-sub category model:
    URL = http://www.example.com
    Parameter = category_id
    method = POST

Now for root level category we pass category_id = 0, which return categories :
    C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6

Now to get sub-categories of each of category C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6 i have to pass its id in the same api one by one . Consider if 1 api call takes 5 seconds then 6 api calls will take 30 seconds. & in actual i have to call about 600 apis one after other to get all the categories & sub-categories together. Is there any way to save that time by calling these api together ?

I am using 2 methods: one to call api & other to receive response. I can call all the apis together but how do i differentiate response? I cant differentiate which response is for which api call?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to enable a server call in which you pass the IDs that you need.

E.g. http://www.example.com/request?categoryIDs=1,18,44

The server could then perform the look-up itself, in one go, and pass you back the category that you need.

Comment: I dont have any server side access so i cant change anything on that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`NSOperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). You can set the number of concurrent operations with `maxConcurrentOperationCount`. You might also want to check AFNetworking, which abstracts some of the boilerplate code.

Comment: could you please explain more regarding this NSOperationQueue ? I havent worked with this before & how this would help me to diffrentiate between the responses of various Apis called together?

Comment: This comment field is too short for a thorough explanation :). But basically you add your operations (either blocks or `NSOperation` subclasses) and they're run concurrently on the background thread. You should check [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1)].